# New baseboard on old wood floors

Tags: floor, hardwood-floor, baseboard, hardwood-refinishing

We are getting our floors refinished and I would like to replace the baseboard + shoe moulding with baseboard only. The problem is the original wood floor installation used shoe, so right now, shoe is needed to cover up the gaps. My installer said easiest thing is just to use shoe again, but was wondering if that's the only option possible, or if there's some kind of thicker baseboard that could help us here. I think just another 1/4" or 1/2" of baseboard width could help us here.[image]

Comment: There are baseboard moulding that have a thicker shoe like bottom on them, if thick enough to cover is a question.  Would go to local building supply store and see what they have.  Take measurements of widest gaps, don't guess.

Comment: How thick is the door trim?

Comment: How thick as the original base?

Comment: Original base = 1/2" thick

Comment: How about the door trim? how thick is that? If the base is thicker than that I will look odd, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> My installer said easiest thing is just to use shoe again.

Yes, I would absolutely do this.

What do you have against shoe molding anyways? If you're concerned about a perceived "loss of floor space" then wouldn't you have the same result with thicker baseboards?

---

Imagine for a moment that you were able to hide the flooring under the baseboards. Okay, so take a wild guess at what will happen if you ever need to refinish the flooring or replace it with new flooring; you'll end up in the same exact situation.

If you're honestly thinking "well I'll just remove the baseboard if that ever happens". Well then you're dealing not only with a floor project but will likely have to re-paint the walls.

Comment: The look of a baseboard over a wood floor is much better, I think, than the look of shoe molding. Just looks cleaner/crisper, and is what I should've done originally. Hope others dont make the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the door trim is thicker than the base so it ends nicely at the doors. If you need thicker base, you could add plinth blocks at the bottoms of the door trim, that is how it was done "back in the day".

You could locate or custom order base that is 1" thick but rabbeted at the top to a thinner perhaps 3/4" at the top so a standard top mold will have a better proportion with the base.

Tip: Sometimes when I ran base in a home with no shoe and the flooring was too short of the wall by a fraction, I would cut little pieces of shim to keep the bottom of the base rolled out a little more than the top just so it covered the gap at the floor, but not so much that it was detectable that there was a curve in the base overall.